# Laravel Pagination Appends Not Keeping Search Data

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I've been able to implement the pagination and appends() on my form and it does show the proper values in the url on page 2, though it doesn't actually bring the values back into the form/query, it simply resets the actual data being searched for and displays all.

Here is my form code and the appends.

```
{{ Form::open(array('class' => 'stdform', 'method' => 'post', 'name' => 'all')) }}

<input type="text" name="srch_lname" class="input-large" 
value="{{ Input::old('srch_lname', Session::get('srch_lname')) }}" />

<input type="text" name="srch_fname" class="input-large" 
value="{{ Input::old('srch_fname', Session::get('srch_fname')) }}" />
.
.
.
 <?php echo $employees->appends(array("srch_lname" => Session::get('srch_lname'),
 "srch_fname" => Session::get('srch_fname') ))->links(); ?>
```

And my **Controller**

```
public function getIndex() {

    $srch_lname = Session::get('srch_lname');
    $srch_fname = Session::get('srch_fname');


    $employees = vEmployees::co()->restrictions()
        ->where('lastname', 'LIKE', $srch_lname . '%')
        ->where('firstname', 'LIKE', $srch_fname . '%')
        ->paginate(10);

    return View::make('employees.index')
        ->with('employees', $employees)
        ->with('title', 'Users');
}

public function postIndex() {

    if (Input::has('btnSearch')) {

        return Redirect::to('/employees')->with('search', 1)
            ->with('srch_lname', Input::get('srch_lname'))
            ->with('srch_fname', Input::get('srch_fname'));
    else {
        return Redirect::to('/employees');
    }
}
```

**Full Form**

```
{{ Form::open(array('class' => 'stdform', 'method' => 'post', 'name' => 'all')) }}
    <div class="stepContainer">
        <div class="formwiz content">
            <h4 class="widgettitle">Search for an Employee</h4>
            <p>
                <label>Lastname</label>
                <span class="field">
                  <input type="text" name="srch_lname" class="input-large" 
                    value="{{ Input::old('srch_lname', Session::get('srch_lname')) }}" />
                </span>
            </p>
            <p>
                <label>Firstname</label>
                <span class="field">
                  <input type="text" name="srch_fname" class="input-large" 
                    value="{{ Input::old('srch_fname', Session::get('srch_fname')) }}" />
                </span>
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="actionBar" style="text-align: right;">
        <button class="btn btn-primary" name="btnSearch" value="1">
            Search for Employee(s)
        </button>
    </div>
{{ Form::close() }}
```

Comment: Can you post the code for the entire form?

Comment: Updated question with the full form.

Comment: when the input is empty i do: `Session::flash('_old_input', Session::get('_old_input'));` if the input is not empty i do: `$request->flash();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working! I continued to do some research and running the search through POST was really a major issue in adding that gap between the search itself and holding the data into the GET method of pagination.

I'll run through everything I did below for anyone in the future having the same issue.

I first created a **Route** that would direct to a new function in my EmployeesController

```
Route::get('emp_srch', 'EmployeesController@search');
```

And created the new function in the **Controller**

```
    public function search() {

    $srch_lname = Input::get('srch_lname');
    $srch_fname = Input::get('srch_fname');


    $employees = vEmployees::co()->restrictions()
        ->where('lastname', 'LIKE', $srch_lname . '%')
        ->where('firstname', 'LIKE', $srch_fname . '%')
        ->orderBy('lastname')
        ->orderBy('firstname')
        ->paginate(10);

    Session::flash('_old_input', Input::all());

    return View::make('employees.index')
        ->with('employees', $employees)
        ->with('title', 'Users')
        ->with('pagetitle', 'Employees')

}
```

It's essentially the function I had in the getIndex though rearranging the way the search was functioning I believe was the defining factor in actually getting this to work in my case.

I also changed the url on the form, which directed to my new Route. As well as changing the form so it uses the GET Method and no longer POST.

`{{ Form::open(array('url' => 'emp_srch', 'class' => 'stdform', 'method' => 'get')) }}`

I do want to thank **vladsch** and **whoacowboy** for helping push me in the right direction(s).

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass your inputs to the view so that Input::old() has values to work with after the redirect from postIndex to getIndex.

in getIndex(), add to View::make()

```
    ->with('input', [ 'srch_lname'=> $srch_lname, 'srch_fname' => $srch_fname ]);
```

Comment: Nothing changed when I added that code. It's able to grab the old input after search on the first page, my issue is somehow getting the input from page1 to page 2.

Comment: try adding Session::flash('_old_input', Input::all()); to postIndex before the redirect. It will make it available in the redirected page.

Comment: I flashed the data and it's still bringing up the same case, showing in the url appends while not actually using the saved data.Ex: `/employees?btnSearch=1&srch_lname=l&srch_fname=&page=2` but the search results and field are now reset.

Comment: I tried adding the Session::flash to the getIndex and it did happen to keep the search fields updated on page 2. But that was the only thing different as the results were still reset.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you do not have the `pageSearch` value in your pagination query string. Try this.

```
<?php echo $employees->appends(
    array("btnSearch" => "1",
      "srch_lname" => Session::get('srch_lname'),
      "srch_fname" => Session::get('srch_fname') )
    )->links(); ?>
```

Comment: It does add the btnSearch value up on the URL when going over to the next page but it still doesn't actually use the input on the second page.

Comment: @Josh What is the output when you `dd($request->all());`

Comment: Gives me an undefined variable of request.

Comment: Sorry, you need to inject the request  `public function postIndex(Request $request) {`

Comment: I believe I did it right and it's still saying it's undefined.

`public function postIndex(Request $request) {
        if (Input::has('btnSearch')) {`

And I'm putting my dd right before the links() portion.

Comment: That should work. Try `dd(Input::all());` in that same method.

Answer (score 1):

I made a small sample but since I don't have your employees I just used the User model and commented out the filtering, just used as a test to pass and get input values.

Note the change to Input:: from Session, in getIndex() and in the form for $employees->appends(). Use Input instead of Session, I did not see anywhere in your code where you save the filter values in session variables.

I also changed the Redirect::to() to pass the parameters in the URL since it is a get method.

I tested and the filter values are passed to getIndex() and the form fields, also the inputs get properly passed by pagination links.

```
class EmployeeController extends BaseController
{
    public
    function getIndex()
    {

        $srch_lname = Input::get('srch_lname');
        $srch_fname = Input::get('srch_fname');

        $employees = User::query()
            //->where('lastname', 'LIKE', $srch_lname . '%')
            //->where('firstname', 'LIKE', $srch_fname . '%')
            ->paginate(10);

        // make input available for page's form fields as old input
        Session::flash('_old_input', Input::all());

        return View::make('employees')
            ->with('employees', $employees)
            ->with('title', 'Users');
    }

    public
    function postIndex()
    {
        if (Input::has('btnSearch'))
        {
            return Redirect::to('/employees?search=1&srch_lname=' . urlencode(Input::get('srch_lname')) . '&srch_fname=' . urlencode(Input::get('srch_fname')));
            //return Redirect::to('/employees')->with('search', 1)
            //    ->with('srch_lname', Input::get('srch_lname'))
            //    ->with('srch_fname', Input::get('srch_fname'));
        }
        else
        {
            return Redirect::to('/employees');
        }
    }
}
```

Form and ->appends():

```
{{ Form::open(array('class' => 'stdform', 'method' => 'post', 'name' => 'all')) }}
<div class="stepContainer">
    <div class="formwiz content">
        <h4 class="widgettitle">Search for an Employee</h4>
        <p>
            <label>Lastname</label>
                <span class="field">
                  <input type="text" name="srch_lname" class="input-large"
                      value="{{ Input::old('srch_lname', Session::get('srch_lname')) }}" />
                </span>
        </p>
        <p>
            <label>Firstname</label>
                <span class="field">
                  <input type="text" name="srch_fname" class="input-large"
                      value="{{ Input::old('srch_fname', Session::get('srch_fname')) }}" />
                </span>
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="actionBar" style="text-align: right;">
    <button class="btn btn-primary" name="btnSearch" value="1">
        Search for Employee(s)
    </button>
</div>
{{ Form::close() }}
<?php echo $employees->appends(array("srch_lname" => Input::get('srch_lname'),
    "srch_fname" => Input::get('srch_fname') ))->links(); ?>
```

Comment: BTW, in your original code the postIndex() method is missing a closing } before the else.

Comment: Yeah that was just from me posting it off Sublime to here, I'm sure it would have thrown an error if it was truly missing. lol